# Choosing the correct NodePort

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Usually we expose our Kubenretes services through an managed K8s/GCP Ingress with auto-assigned NodePorts, but for some [use](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-multicluster-ingress) [cases](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-federation/ingress/) we need to specify a static NodePort ourselves.

The [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) says that we need to make sure to avoid port collissions:

> you need to take care about possible port collisions yourself

**Q: How should how we choose the correct NodePort?**

Should we / do we have to allocate our static NodePort from the *flag-configured range (default: 30000-32767)*?

Or rather not from this range to avoid collisions with these auto-assigned ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more about not assigning the same port manually to multiple services then anything else. If you have a manualy defined NodePort it will not get assigned to dynamic service, so yes, you should use port from this range.

Comment: Thank you, that was the info I was looking for. Meanwhile I tried it and verified it works. As a note to others I would suggest to not change any automatically assigned port if using some of the GCP ingress machinery, as these are pretty slow to update their backends and your site may become unavailable if you change the port. You can still make the automatic assignment static by getting the assigned port and add it as a nodePort in your service definition.